# Unable to mput all the files through sftp in the remote server using expect

Tags: linux, bash, sftp, expect

I'm trying to `mput` all files present in the directory : `/Test/XML/` into a remote sftp server with the help of `expect` utility.

I've around 320 files in the directory: /Test/XML/.

The size of each file is around 0.1 MB.

There's no error observed.

Here's my code:

```
cd /Test/XML/

/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn /usr/bin/sftp ${user_name}@${HOSTNAME}
expect "password:"
send "${passwd}\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /test\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "mkdir XML\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /test/XML\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "mput *\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOF
```

But the problem here is, `mput *` is transferring only 4 files instead of transferring all the 320 files.
Not sure, why it's not able to transfer all the 320 files in the remote server.

Any help is most welcome.

Comment: did you get any error before exist the script ?? i mean connection aborted or something related to proxy ?

Comment: Did you check if you can turn off interactive prompting (`PROMPT` command)?

Comment: you can also try recursive by replacing `mput` with `put -r *` so that it will transfer files along with folder if any.

Comment: @ThiruShetty: I ran the script in debug mode.There's no error observed. I need to transfer files only.

Comment: all files with same extension ?? like .xml ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Not sure, but how to turn off interactive prompting?

Comment: I am not certain if it is standardised or not. I have seen that the simple command `PROMPT` toggles the state to the opposite value and I have also seen that the command `PROMPT OFF` explicitly disables it.

Comment: @ThiruShetty: Not all of them are of same extension, most of them are like : `*.xml_move` and some are `*.xml`

Comment: I think the issue it `timeout`.. can you try `set timeout -1` (infinity) before you call `mput` ? hope it works

Comment: `set timeout -1` has to be included inside the `expect`? or does it needs to be declared outside of it?because `sftp` will not consider `set timeout -1` inside `expect` utility.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `prompt` is a common command in `ftp` client, not `sftp`.

Comment: @AshishK Do you get the same problem when executing `sftp` manually, without `expect`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Manually it's able to transfer all the files in remote server.With `expect`, only few are transferred. Forgot to mention that the size of the files is bit large. So, when i schedule it in cron, it takes time.

Comment: You should edit this important information into your question. And also include an output of your script.

Comment: `set timeout` is part of `expect` not part of `sftp` so you don't `send` it to the FTP server, you just put it as the first line in your expect script.

Comment: Thanks @ThiruShetty and @MartinPrikryl, i guess `set timeout -1` worked :-) There were large number of files to be transferred which were of considerable large size, maybe that's why it was stuck earlier.

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Comment: AshishK, you should add an answer for your question so other readers don't have to dig through the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @ThiruShetty for the hint of using `set timeout -1` in the `expect` utility.

Actually, i had a lot of files(~320-350) to be transferred(sftp) to a remote server.
With the normal execution of `sftp` using `expect` utility, it was able to transfer only a few files, not all of them which i wanted.

After inserting `set timeout -1` inside `expect`, it solved the problem of timeout.

Here's the final code:

```
cd /Test/XML/

/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
set timeout -1
spawn /usr/bin/sftp ${user_name}@${HOSTNAME}
expect "password:"
send "${passwd}\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /test\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "mkdir XML\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /test/XML\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "mput *\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOF
```